# How to set feature engineering for day of a week?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering, feature-weighting

Apologies if this is a very basic question. I'm currently learning data science and was wondering to help validating what I'm trying to do.

So I have a model set up to predict event duration by minutes, so I'm trying to do linear regression. However, I noticed that the data for Monday is much higher compared to the rest of the week. I want to do feature engineering on it. Can you suggest the best way to do this?

What I was told was to create a feature that basically says when day of week == Monday, set the value to 1, otherwise set value to 0 (zero) for the rest of the week. Is this the right approach?

Here's an example of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Creating a variable corresponding to whether the day is Monday is probably reasonable.

But it looks from your graph that there might be some other differences between days beyond that. Normally we would create variables corresponding to each day except for one which becomes the reference category.

Statisticians call this 'dummy coding' as you turn one variable with many levels into several binary 'dummy' variables. You would rarely do this by hand though; most statistical software will do it automatically if you specify that the variable encodes categorical information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I quite understand though. Would you be able to give me instructions on how to do it using my example?

Comment: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)

Comment: @fokusfocus you might also find this approach called 'one-hot' encoding.  It's exactly the same thing as dummy coding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot